# Error in kernelUD: xy should be defined in two dimensions

Tags: r, statistics, spatial

I am running a Kernal density estimation in R with supermarket location data extracted from R. But while running this script I get an error

```
 kde_output <- kernelUD(ls, h="href", grid = 1000)
```

> Error in kernelUD(ls, h = "href", grid = 1000) :
> xy should be defined in two dimensions

Comment: Can you show the `str(ls)`

Comment: Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 128 obs. of  15 variables:
  .. ..$ F_id      : chr [1:128] "way/28162269" "way/29280846" "way/44978440" "way/48578254" ..@ coords     : num [1:128, 1:3] 13.1 13.1 13 13.1 13 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2..$ : chr [1:3] "coords.x1" "coords.x2" "coords.x3"@ bbox       : num [1:3, 1:2] 13 47.7 0 13.1 47.8 ...- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2. ..$ : chr [1:3] "coords.x1" "coords.x2" "coords.x3".. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot